# using mustache templates with jersey

Tags: java, template-engine, mustache, jersey-2.0

I want to integrate Mustache-based templates with Jersey 2.

In my **pom.xml** I have:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-mvc-mustache</artifactId>
<version>2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

My resource class looks like this:

```
@Path(value = "/appstatus")
public class AppStatusChecker
{

    @Template(name = "/index.mustache")
    @GET
    public Context getStatus() {
        return new Context(4);
    }

    public static class Context {
        public Integer value;

        public Context(final Integer value) {
           this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In my **web.xml** I have this:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasepath.mustache</param-name>
    <param-value>/templates</param-value>
</init-param>
```

And when the app is deployed, under `WEB-INF/classes` I have a folder `templates` with `index.mustache` inside. The content is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple mustache test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is mustacheee</h1>
    {{value}}
  </body>
</html>
```

What I see after calling the myapp/appstatus URL is: `{"value":4}` but I would expect some HTML. Is there some important part of the setup I am missing?

Comment: This looks strange `{{#value}}{{value}}{{/value}}`... Could the middle one be just `{{.}}`?

Comment: @brasofilo: I updated my mustache template. Even with this correction all I see when I load the page is `{"value":4}`. So nothing related to HTML...

Comment: I don't know Java/Jersey... how's the object that feeds into mustache? I guess it's the resource class that does that, but what's its output?

Comment: What I have in my resource class is equivalent to:
`public Viewable getStatus() {
return new Viewable("/index.mustache", new Context(4));
}`
So the Context object is _merged_ with the mustache template

Answer (score 4):

I had to register my provider like:

```
    final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().property(
            MustacheMvcFeature.TEMPLATE_BASE_PATH, "templates"
    ).register(
            MustacheMvcFeature.class
    ).packages("com.example");

    return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
```

Not sure if you are using Grizzly. But, maybe this will help someone.

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/mvc.html#mvc.registration